# Grid-atoricts question

Tags: combinatorics

I have a combinatorics problem that is driving me crazy.
I have too few weapons to attack it.
Due to my poor english, I will try to explain it in an easier way.

I have a sqare grid of $n\times n$ cells $(n>2)$ and I need to put some points in some cells following $3$ basic rules:

$\qquad(1)$ I can't put any point in cells of the main diagonal (upper-left/lower right).

$\qquad(2)$ Every row and every column must have $2$ and only $2$ points.

$\qquad(3)$ Every row and every column must be unique; in other words, I can't have two or more rows/columns with points in the same position.

My question is: how many right configurations can I obtain, in terms of $n$?

I think (based on my attempts) that there is some sort of hidden symmetric rule.
Does anyone have any idea on how to attack this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Emanuele

Comment: Just to check I've understood the rules correctly: is it right that when n=3 there is only one valid configuration and when n=4 there are six valid configurations?

Comment: Yes. For n=3 is trivial. For n=4 i found 3 solution  chat can be doubled swapping upper "triangle" with lower one.

Comment: Thanx to Fimpellizieri  for test corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant of the [ménage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem).  Ordinarily we have $n$ men (the row indices) married to $n$ women (the column indices) who sit around a table with $2n$ seats, so that men sit next to women and women sit next to men, and nobody sits next to their spouse.  In this version, we have two differences:

1. the $2n$ male-female partners are simply "holding hands" with people of the other sex who are not their partner (i.e., we don't have fixed table sizes), and
2. no two males are holding hands with the same two females.

This results of "tables" of sizes $6,8,\ldots$ which partition $2n$, and we use $P$ to denote the partition.

We'll adapt [Bogart and Doyle's slick ménage formula proof](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/menage/menage/menage.html) to suit.  Everything follows mostly the same way, except we're now placing the couples on the graph $G_P:=\cup_{p \in P} C_p$ and summing over the legal partitions $P$.  We get:
$$
a_n=\sum_{\substack{\text{partition } P \text{ of } 2n \\ p \in P \implies p \in \{6,8,\ldots\}}} \frac{2^{|P|}}{|\mathrm{aut}(G_P)|} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\, d_k[P]\, k!\, 2^{|P|}\ (n-k)!^2
$$
where we include-exclude over a choice of $k$ couples who must hold hands.  There's $\binom{n}{k}$ such choices of couples, which we assign in one of $k!$ ways to one of the $d_k[P]$ placements of $k$ non-overlapping dominos on the graph $G_P$ (which we find a formula for below).  For each cycle in $G_P$, we choose where the men/women sit, and the remaining $n-k$ women and $n-k$ men sit in any women-assigned or men-assigned seats.  Finally, we divide by the number of gender-preserving automorphisms of $G_P$, otherwise we count configurations multiple times, which is equal to $|\mathrm{aut}(G_P)|/2^{|P|}$ and we observe
$$
|\mathrm{aut}(G_P)| = \Big( \prod_{i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}} s(i)! \Big) \Big( \prod_{p \in P} p \Big)
$$
where $s(i)$ is the number of $i$'s in $P$.  (Bogart and Doyle didn't have an $|\mathrm{aut}(G_P)|$ term, but with their fixed graph $C_{2n}$, this term is constant, whereas our $|\mathrm{aut}(G_P)|$ is not constant so we need to account for it within the summation.)

Bogart and Doyle's proof also points out that $$d_k[\{2n\}] = \frac{2n}{2n-k} \binom{2n-k}{k}.$$  If $P=\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$, this generalizes to $$d_k[P] = \sum_{\substack{a_1,\ldots,a_m \in \{0,1,\ldots\} \\ \text{which sum to } k}} \prod_{i=1}^m d_{a_i}[\{p_i\}]$$
and we take $d_{a_i}[\{p_i\}]=0$ when $a_i>p_i/2$.

The following code implements this in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/):

```
d_orig:=function(k,n)
  return (2*n/(2*n-k))*Binomial(2*n-k,k);
end;;

d:=function(k,P)
  local n,m,count,Q,A;
  n:=Sum(P)/2;
  m:=Size(P);
  count:=0;

  Q:=OrderedPartitions(k+m,m)-1;
  for A in Q do
    if(not ForAll([1..m],i->A[i]<=P[i]/2)) then continue; fi;
    count:=count+Product([1..m],i->d_orig(A[i],P[i]/2));
  od;

  return count;
end;;

aut_size:=function(P)
  return Product(List(List(Set(P),i->Number(P,j->i=j)),i->Factorial(i)))*Product(P);
end;;

a:=function(n)
  local Ptns;

  Ptns:=RestrictedPartitions(2*n,[6,8..2*n]);

  return Sum(Ptns,P->Sum([0..n],k->(-1)^k*Binomial(n,k)*d(k,P)*Factorial(k)*Factorial(n-k)^2/aut_size(P)));
end;;
```

and if we compute the numbers up to $n=20$ using `for n in [3..20] do Print(n," ",a(n),"\n"); od;`, we get:

```
3 1
4 6
5 156
6 5620
7 269130
8 16616796
9 1302305536
10 126169436016
11 14802593296140
12 2069271914687560
13 339915497582948496
14 64837968520335428496
15 14214382941525362069656
16 3549527421297391994169360
17 1001677426115759811101034240
18 317219478762148442235395675776
19 112034824611937954683531536904336
20 43880470950820929237567549934682976
```

(As a cross-check, I computed the numbers for $n \in \{3,\ldots,8\}$ using an alternative method involving $3 \times n$ Latin rectangles, which agree with the above.)

Comment: My question was born EXACTLY to solve the nemage question. I tried (failing) to reduce the problem in a grid nxn. I didn't know that this was a famous problem. I didn't know (perhaps due to my scolar english) why the grid isn't a right rappresentation of menage problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Rebecca you have opened a door to me so now i must study this things. when i built the grid i thought in this term: a man is a point (cols) and a women is a line(rows).All line intersect  2 point (ends) and a point is a common for two lines (vertex). The restriction is that some points can't intersect some lines (no partnerns togheter). In this way the third restriction is a result of costruction. Now i haven't undestand why my rappresentation in the grid is not a right rappresentation of menage problem!?. If you have a few time can you clear me this thing ?